# How to remove the path from an attachment when calling addAttachmentData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

When adding an attachment to an email, the file name gets it's complete path.

For a file located in:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/C3BBAA5F-07FE-4E26-9661-CB492E06BD2E/Documents/
```

I'm getting as a result, a file named:

```
_var_mobile_Applications_C3BBAA5F-07FE-4E26-9661-CB492E06BD2E_Documents_Clock.sqlite
```

When I need my filename to be:

```
Clock.sqlite
```

Here's my code:

```
NSString *path = [self getDatabaseFilePath];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3" fileName:path];
```

How can I get the attachment to have only the filename and extension, without the complete path?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
NSString *path = [self getDatabaseFilePath];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3" fileName:[path lastPathComponent]];
```

Comment: You were 4 seconds behind me, but you had the same correct idea... so +1 to you!