# Xcode 6 MFMailComposeViewController does NOT work

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I try to upgrade my App to iOS 8. App runs perfect in iOS 7 and iOS 6 (In my iPhone and iPad).

**But in iOS 8 NOT (iPhone 6 simulator).**

**And NOT in iPhone 5 simulator and any iPhone simulator (Xcode 6.0)**

I simply try to send mail.

```c
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComp = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    mailComp setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        [mailComp setSubject:@"Subject test"];
        [mailComp setMessageBody:@"Message body test" isHTML:NO];
        [self presentViewController:mailComp animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

        if (error) {
            // Error handling 
        }
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
```

The error message:

**Is not a valid email address.**

**ViewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed.**

**{Message=Service Connection Interrupted}**

I have observed that in iPhone 6 Simulator **you can not create a Gmail Account** but I have created an iCloud Mail Account (New feature, I think)

I do not know if this is the problem. Please, Is there anyone in this situation?

Comment: I have nearly the same, since I am using as well xcode6 and ios8, although it was working before, although I see the screen and have no crash - the setMessageBody does not work anymore for me (  [controller setMessageBody: tmpAnswers isHTML:YES]; )

Comment: I updated my devices to iOS8 and they can send mails. I think it is a problem in the simulators of the Xcode6. Or maybe exists another new way to send mail.

Comment: It must be a bug, same with `UIActivityViewController` sharing to mail - working fine on device but not on any simulator

Comment: I downloaded the sample from Apple it has the same error though. Heres the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/samplecode/MessageComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010161)

If you run the sample code it has the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this topic: [MFMailComposeViewController dismisses right away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696835/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-dismisses-right-away)

The response from Max seems to deal with this problem. It´s not the mail address or the mail account.